# IE 9 missing content

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm note sure what's going on here - it feels like a browser bug, not an SO bug.

[image]

Comment: came back after reboot - shortly before i tried to view a sharepoint 2010 web database for the first time and my browser just went to all black - maybe that was the cause.  also i'm on server 2008r2 with aero desktop enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content displays on my machine, IE9 on a Windows 7, 64 bit. It may have been a temporary issue with the site, or an issue on your machine / build. ([Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880435/how-inefficient-are-virtual-table-joins))

[image: SO on IE9]